# MVC page level security based on DB in addition to role

Tags: security, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")], etc. to control access to pages, but in addition to that, my client wants more. We have Users who can create SubUsers and determine what screens they can access. For example, User 1 might indicate SubUser 1 might get screens 1-4 but not 5-8 (using numbers for simplicity here). SubUser 2 might get the odd screens, SubUser gets the even ones.

This doesn't seem like a Role-Based security thing. I was going to create a screen for Users to choose a SubUser, then get to another screen with checkboxes for every screen and check off the ones that SubUser can reach. Easy enough.

My question is, how to enforce that in the app?  The obvious way is, on every single get, hit the DB, passing in that username and an ID for that screen and seeing if they have access. Is there a better way, to avoid hitting the DB for that check on every page? Since there's no session object, I can't get an array (just once) of page IDs they can access and store it in session.

Answer (score 0):

```
     public class ServiceCheckAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
        {
            public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
            {
                // check user role
                // Check if user has access to this action/page
                if (userHasAccess)
                {
                    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
                }
                else
                {
                    filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new
                    RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Error", action = "AccessDenied" }));
                }
            }
        }
```

on each controller where you need to check user accessibility add this attribute `[ServiceCheckAttribute]`